# vim plugin not working: schlepp

Tags: vim, plugins

Yes, I've checked the other similar questions.

I manually installed the [schlepp](https://github.com/zirrostig/vim-schlepp) plugin. It's in the bundle directory, next to plugins that are working. In fact, I also put it in the plugin directory.

I put the runtime line in my .vimrc, and verified in vim that it's working. I even did vim -V, and saw that vim is looking in the schlepp folder. And yet, if I do ":help schlepp", it says, "Sorry, no help for schlepp."

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation for the plugin, you'll find the instructions for manual installation, which hint quite distinctly at using a plugin manager.

Presuming you have indeed copied the plugin correctly, I guess you forgot `:helptags doc`.

The plugin seems rather unmaintained. Why not have a look at [vim-move](https://github.com/matze/vim-move) instead?

Comment: I installed it on a different machine, this time using Vundle. This time, it at least gives the help file, but it still doesn't work as described. I've filed a bug report.

Comment: @user1889034 I added a hint for a similar plugin!

Comment: I used a mapping to move lines up and down. What I need now is a way to move selections *within* a line. I even found a plugin for single words (which I have working), and the brass ring is to be able to move multiple words at once.

Comment: So I had a quick look at schlepp, turns out, this might be the only plugin that can do this. BUT they write how they were inspired by [more instantly better vim](http://radar.oreilly.com/2013/10/more-instantly-better-vim.html) and there it is explained how to do it without a plugin...

Comment: For whatever reason, that didn't work for me, either. However, I've had good luck with the instructions I found here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Drag_words_with_Ctrl-left/right